# Add Key/Pair value to an object dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

This is how my data looks:

```
[{
    "key": 111,
    "Students_Info": [{
      "recordId": 111
    }],
    "Adress_Info": {
      "position": 1,-- -- -- > How do I insert this ?
      "city": Delhi
    }
  },
  {
    "key": 222,
    "Students_Info": [{
      "recordId": 222
    }],
    "Adress_Info": {
      "position": 2,-- -- -- > How do I insert this ?
      "city": Delhi
    }
  }
]
```

Suppose if the total array count is 2 I need to insert their positions in the mentioned place above.

This is what I tried

```
data.forEach((element, value) => {
    data.push("position:"+ value)
});
```

But this has syntax errors and I'm not sure how to insert them.

Comment: `element.Students_Info[0].position = value;`

Comment: Can there be more than one element in `Students_Info`? Should they all get the same position?

Comment: Can you please explain how these positions would be calculated if more than one item in `Students_Info` is in each object?

Comment: This would add the position in the main object, not inside the `Students_Info` array. @ArmanCharan

Comment: @Everyone- Sorry it should be in the Address_Info not Student_Info

Comment: @Barmar - No there will be one Student_Info and the position should be in Address_Info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For additional context, see [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```js
const data = [
  aDataEntryWithRecordId(111),
  aDataEntryWithRecordId(222),
  aDataEntryWithRecordId(333),
  aDataEntryWithRecordId(444),
  aDataEntryWithRecordId(555),
]

data.forEach(
  (entry, index) => {
    const position = index + 1
    entry.Address_Info.position = position
  }
)

console.log(data)

function aDataEntryWithRecordId(recordId) {
  return {
    key: recordId,
    Students_Info: [{ recordId }],
    Address_Info: { city: 'Delhi' }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you please check

Comment: getting error as Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'position')

Comment: If I use entry.position = position this displayes outside Address_Info and the position starts from 6 as I have array of 5 items